# Custom SupervisorStrategy for Akka System Guardian

Tags: akka, akka-supervision, akka-actor

According to the [Akka docs on the System Guardian](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/supervision.html#_system__The_System_Guardian), if a top-level actor  throws an `Exception`, it will be restarted indefinitely (with 2 exceptions - no pun intended).

My actor system has 1 and only 1 top-level actor: `Initializer`. If `Initializer` throws an exception, I would like a different `SuervisorStrategy` applied to it, if at all possible:

- Restart `Initializer` up to 3 times
- If that doesn't work, *then* stop/terminate it

How could I implement this custom strategy for the System Guardian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the guardian supervision strategy with the configuration key `akka.guardian-supervisor-strategy` in your `application.conf`, which has the default "akka.actor.DefaultSupervisorStrategy".

See this section of the docs for more info: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/configuration.html#akka-actor